# https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums sometimes returns nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I've been experimenting with the Facebook API using the Javascript SDK.  Whenever I'm logged into Facebook I can pretty reliably call:

```js
function init() {
    // Called after loading the Facebook SDK
    FB.api("/me", function(response) {
        console.log(response.first_name); // "John" (always works)
    });
}
```

But I also want to get a users photo albums (when they click a link) and for some reason this call only works intermittently:

```js
$(document).ready(function) {

    $("#get-albums-link").click(function() {
        var accessToken = "456"; // Just an example
        FB.api("/me/albums?access_token=" + accessToken, function(response) {
            console.log(response); // An empty object about 40% of the time
        });
    });

});
```

When this happens I can open up a new tab and verify that even direct queries return this same empty result (note that although this could be an authorizations issue, there is no obvious indication that it is; it is simply an empty JSON object):

```
<!-- An HTTPS GET at https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=456 -->
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the access_token you are using has the photos permission?

Comment: I have not spent time with the Facebook API caching but I have seen the same problem with jQuery's ajax() calls.  Explicitly calling queries with jsonp or setting a nocache flag helps the browser continue to make calls.  You may want to start with a facebook cache control

Comment: @FelipeBrahm, it should be a correct access_token, because after all, sometimes I do get an Albums object.  It's just that other times, I don't.  Could definitely be a caching issue, given that it seems to work correctly for about 15 minutes before returning empty objects.  If I wait 20 minutes and refresh it usually works again for another 15 minutes.

Comment: Try doing a GET to /me/permissions?access_token=... to verify you have the right permissions.

Comment: @FelipeBrahm - When the call to /me/albums?access_token=... returns nothing, a call to /me/permissions?access_token=... returns `{"data":[]}`.  When the call to /me/albums?access_token=... returns real data, a call to /me/permissions?access_token=... returns `{"data":[{"installed":1,"user_photos":1,"friends_photos":1}]}`

Comment: @DylanValade, I switched out the FB.api() call with an $.ajax() call, passing `cache: false` in the settings map, but unfortunately this didn't seem to work either. If Facebook allows one to pass in a similar kind of "cache" flag in their API calls I am unaware how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As Felipe pointed out above, the access token can be the issue, as not having permissions set will return {"data":[]}. Try it yourself: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums

Also, even if it is a valid auth_token, the SDK doesn't require one, so don't use it. You might end up with something like graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=123423&access_token=981234 (second access token added by SDK). I, personally, don't know how the FB.api function is built, but just follow the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't want to jinx myself, but the problem seems to have gone away.  I wish I had a good explanation.  The things that are different now are: (1) It's been a few weeks since I've touched the code.  Maybe things just needed "settle" with my newly-registered app on Facebook.  (2) I don't use the `FB.api(...)` calls to retrieve albums, I use jQuery's `$.ajax(..)` directly. (3) In the aforementioned `$.ajax(...)` calls I _do_ pass in the access token.